# Passing class to label from forms.py in ChoiceField/MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

How can I pass a class to label in the field MultipleChoiceField in forms.py to my template.

For example, I want my check box to look like this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    [...]
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Option 2</label>
    [...]
</div>
```

So I create a form that looks like this:

```
    class Form(forms.Form):
        field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MY_OPTION,
                                                 widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input',
                                                                                      'label': 'custom-control-label'}))
```

But in my template the form looks like this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    [...]
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" label="custom-control-label" id="customCheck1">
    <label for="customCheck1">Option 2</label>
    [...]
</div>
```

So the label goes to the input field, not the label. How can I add a label to the **label field(`<label></label>`)**?

### Edit [CheckboxSelectMultiple]

It's Work:

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_OPTION, widget=CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input'}))
```

In the template:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  {{ form.field }}
  {{ form.field|label_with_classes:"custom-control-label" }}
</div>
```

But when I try:

```
field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MY_OPTION, widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input'}))
```

In the template I receive something like this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    [...]
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
    <label for="customCheck1">Option 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
    <label for="customCheck1">Option 3</label></li>
    [...]
    <!--and my label with good class -->
    <label for="customCheck1" class="custom-control-label">Option 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are generating form for creating records in model, I will recommend using modelForm

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the form will be used to create the search function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a template filter that I can use to render the label with custom class:

```
# form_filters.py

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def label_with_classes(field, css):
    """Create the label tag with additional classes.

    Example:
        > {{ form.my_field|label_with_classes:"class1 my_special_class" }}
        > <label for="id_my_field" class="class1 my_special_class">My Field</label>

    Args:
        field: this should be a form field, of type ``BoundField``
        css: this should be a string with one or more class names separated by spaces
    """
    return field.label_tag(attrs={'class': css})
```

Then inside my template, I can do this:

```
{% load form_filters %}
{{ form.some_field|label_with_classes:"custom-control-label" }}
{{ form.some_field }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! it works for CheckboxInput field. But when applying this solution to the field CheckboxSelectMultiple I get the result as above.I can't adjust it properly. Please, can you see my editable part of the question.